# How to override prime-react component CSS styling?

Tags: reactjs, sass, styled-components, react-css-modules, primereact

I am using prime-react to style my React page. But I want a more compact website with very few padding and minimum styling. For this purpose, I want to override a few CSS properties for the prime-react components.

For eg, I am trying to reduce the padding for the MenuBar -

HomePage.js

```
import {React, Component } from 'react';
import { Menubar } from 'primereact/menubar';
import 'primereact/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css';
import 'primereact/resources/primereact.min.css';
import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';
import styled from "styled-components";

export default class HomeMenuBar extends Component {
    // menu code ...

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="card">
                    <Menubar model={this.items} className={this.props.className} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const ComponentView = styled(HomeMenuBar)`
    .p-menubar .p-menubar-root-list > .p-menuitem > .p-menuitem-link {
        padding: 0.1rem 1rem !important;
    }
`;
```

The above code makes no difference to the original styling.
I am trying to make use of [this](https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/tree/master/src/components/megamenu) component.

However, particularly using these styled-components I don't like it. I am new to react and would like to know if there are better alternatives like, storing the CSS properties in another file and then importing it in the required file. I tried this part but it also didn't work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with react over a year and have seen lot of different ways to customise components and so far, I think that styled-components is the most convenient way to customize components if you cook them right.
I love to put all customized components with styled to a separate file near the index.js called styled.js of Component.js and Componnet.styled.js (in the separate folder of course MyComponent/index.js);

In styled.js you export all components like this:

```
export const Container = styled.div`
    .p-menubar .p-menubar-root-list > .p-menuitem > .p-menuitem-link {
        padding: 0.1rem 1rem !important;
    }
`
```

In index.js file you inport them like this:

```
import {Container} from './styled' 
// or import * as Styled from './styled' (if you have a lot of customized components);

export default class HomeMenuBar extends Component {
    // menu code ...

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <div className="card">
                    <Menubar model={this.items} className={this.props.className} />
                </div>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

If you want to try something more like classic css try to look at css-modules.
This article can help https://www.triplet.fi/blog/practical-guide-to-react-and-css-modules/

Comment: How to take care of imports ? I have created two separate files. For the `styled.js` I have put two imports, `import styled from "styled-components";
import HomeMenuBar from './MenuBar'` but it throws an error `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'HomeMenuBar' before initialization`

Comment: I appologize, I have misled you with my mistake in the code. I have wrote:
ComponentView = styled (Home MenuBar)
instead of
ComponentView = styled.div

Comment: If you will whant to use HomeMenuBar as a child of other components and customize it again somwhere elese (may be for some unique case only in one place, usually it happens with buttons or other common components) you can wrap it with styled again like this: 
`CustomMenuBar = styled(HomeMenuBar)
..more styles...`
But in this case inside HomeMenuBar you need to pass a prop className from props
 to a top level container in your render function. In my example it would be the next: 
`<Container className={this.props.className}> `
or even pass all props 
`<Container props={...this.props}>`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [patch-styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-styles), a more declarative way to apply CSS/SCSS modules to your code. Also, check out the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-patch-styles?file=src/pages/FirstPage.module.css) example.